How to use python systemd.journal module to log to a newly created systemd journald namespace
The python example here allows me to log to the systemd journal just by adding logger.info("Hi Mom").  I want to log to a different journal namespace with custom/longer data retention period as explained here in Section 4.1 . I created a journal namespace called pulldicom based on this 2nd link.
I don't know how to specify the use of a different namespace using the JournalHandler from python. I tried specifying the namespace like this:
# Create journal logger
# To non-default namespace allowing to customize log retention to longer.  NOT WORKING
journalHandler = JournalHandler(NAMESPACE='pulldicom', SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER='logging-systemd-python-app')
# To default namespace WORKING
#journalHandler = JournalHandler(SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER='logging-systemd-python-app')

Note that I am not trying to do this from a systemd service, a task for which documentation exists. I am also unsure how to test that my journal namespace alone is working. Create a fake service?

It doesn't have that functionality, and seemingly neither does the underlying libsystemd (sd-journal) library.
Namespaces aren't distinguished by a message field – they are fully isolated journald instances, each with its own sockets, and the library needs to know that it has to connect to a non-standard socket path before sending any messages.
At the moment, libsystemd only has a single function which supports that – there is a namespace-capable variant of the _stream_fd() function, sd_journal_stream_fd_with_namespace(), that is used for attaching a service's stdout to the journal. It would be possible to write a logging handler over this (and would be easier to do so by reimplementing the protocol rather than using library bindings) but so far neither systemd-python nor pystemd provide that.
They all retain syslog compatibility, though, so if you don't need custom fields (aside from the syslog identifier which is still customizable), you can instead use:
SysLogHandler(address="/run/systemd/journal.pulldicom/dev-log")


Thank you.  I thought SysLogHandler was tied to pre systemd syslogd so non-binary logs etc. The directory you specified is under a systemd dir so I am a bit confused. I see a lot of sockets in /run/systemd/journal/ . Assuming "." above is a typo and should be a "/"

It is not. "Syslog" messages normally go to journald (via the standard /dev/log symlinked to /run/systemd/journal/dev-log), but each 'namespace' corresponds to a separate instance of journald which creates its sockets under a different journal.*/ directory.
